# MS Access - Take hourly rate and employee name from another table and multiply by time taken

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am not too sure how to approach this method and was wondering if anyone could assist me.

Basically, I have a table (***tblLogInspection***) where the data is input via the user from separate form (***frmAddInspectionRecord***). I have used vba so that upon a button click all data that has been input will transfer to the table.

What I have is another table (***tblemployeedetails***), i.e. their name and hourly rate. On (***frmAddInspectionRecord***) there is a combo box that is quiered from (***tblemployeedetails***) where the user can select which employee has conducted the work. Upon this data being added to (***tblLogInspection***) I would like a column which takes the hourly rate of the employee that has conducted the work from (***tblemployeedetails***) and multiply it by the TIMETAKEN column in (***tblLogInspection***).

I hope that I have explained this with enough detail. If anyone could help guide me in the right direction I would be so grateful!

Comment: The data source for Access forms is not limited to tables. You could devise a simple Access query from the tables concerned which amongst other things calculates the amount due to the employee, and include a text box with the result in your form. . There's not much need for VBA to do any of this.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am currently having a play around with dlookups to do something similar to what you have said. If I have the calculations going on in a hidden text box and then have it added to the table once the lookup has been done on the form. Do you think this would be the best option?

Comment: It's an option, and only you can tell what is best for you, but in my view if there is unlikely to be a need to vary the calculation manually then you can use a computed field in a query without having to store anything new in a table at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the most straightforward solution to this would be a query (as already suggested by Stewart Ross)

Imagine your tables are set up like this:

> tblemployeedetails:
>   Employee_ID | Employee_Name | HourlyRate
>
> tblLogInspection:
>   Inspection_ID | Employee_ID | TimeTaken

Now, set up a query with a calculated field:

```
SELECT q2.Inspection_ID AND q2.TimeTaken * q1.HourlyRate
FROM tblemployeedetails AS q1
     INNER JOIN tblLogInspection AS q2 ON q1.Employee_ID = q2.Employee_ID
```